# ButtonId in knockoutjs method

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

i have 2 buttons like below:

```
<button id="btnPrevious" class="icon-backward" data-bind="click: $root.GoForWeek"></button>

<button class="icon-forward" data-bind="click: $root.GoForWeek"></button>
```

I want to pass value in my method to know which button is clicked. My method is below:

```
self.GoForWeek= function (data, event) {alert(event.target);


    //want to get id of button to know which button is clicked

        $.ajax({
            //code here
        })
};
```

Comment: Check note 2 in: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the code below for function declaration:

```
self.GoForPreviousWeek = function (data, event) {
```

Now, event.target will tell you which button was clicked. You can then use

> $(event.target)

to access the element in jquery.

You can also use the data variable in this case to access any data you have added to the control thought knockout's 'data' attribute in data binding.

Comment: But event.target is returning [object HTMLButtonElement].

Comment: Did you use $(event.target) in jQuery ? event.Target is the button element. You can also probably use the object directly in javascript code to get its attributes.

Comment: $(event.target) returning [object object]. i have to pass this value as param in ajax call

Comment: Yep, so try to use the following: `self.GoForPreviousWeek = function (data, event) {alert(event.target.id);}` This should help you.

Comment: As pavlo mentioned you need to pass properties i guess, why do you need pass the whole object ? You should use the event.target object, get the corresponding properties and use them. What you are seeing as [object object] is correct, because it is the button object itself.